# MapReduce to count the frequency of the number consonants in words from a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

I need a bit of help with Python code to count the frequency of consonants in a word. Consider the following sample input:

```
"There is no new thing under the sun."
```

Then the required output would be:

```
1 : 2
2 : 3
3 : 2
4 : 1
```

as there are 2 words with 1 consonant, 3 words with 2 consonants, 2 words with 3 consonants and 1 word with 4 consonants.

The following code does a similar job but instead of consonants it counts the frequency of whole words in text file. I know there is only a bit change which loops deeper into the word (I think).

```
def freqCounter(file1, file2):
    freq_dict = {}
    dict_static = {2:0, 3:0, 5:0}
    # get rid of punctuation
    punctuation = re.compile(r'[.?!,"\':;]') # use re.compile() function to convert string into a RegexObject. 
    try:
        with open(file1, "r") as infile, open(file2, "r") as infile2: # open two files at once
            text1 = infile.read()   # read the file
            text2 = infile2.read()
            joined = " ".join((text1, text2)) 
            for word in joined.lower().split(): 
                #remove punctuation mark
                word = punctuation.sub("", word)
                #print word
                l = len(word) # assign l tp be the word's length
                # if corresponding word's length not found in dict
                if l not in freq_dict:
                    freq_dict[l] = 0 # assign the dict key (the length of word) to value = 0
                freq_dict[l] += 1 # otherwise, increase the value by 1
    except IOError as e:     # exception catch for error while reading the file
        print 'Operation failed: %s' % e.strerror
    return freq_dict # return the dictionary
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
with open('conts.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write('oh my god becky look at her butt it is soooo big')

consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
def count_cons(_file):
    results = {}
    with open(_file, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            for word in line.split(' '):
                conts = sum([1 if letter in consonants else 0 for letter in word])
                if conts in results:
                    results[conts] += 1
                else:
                    results[conts] = 1
    return results

print count_cons('conts.txt')
```

Missed the results

```
{1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 1, 4: 1}
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try a simpler approach:

```
from collections import Counter
words = 'There is no new thing under the sun.'
words = words.replace('a', '').replace('e', '').replace('i', '').replace('o', '').replace('u', '')  # you are welcome to replace this with a smart regex

# Now words have no more vowels i.e. only consonants 
word_lengths = map(len, words.split(' '))
c = Counter(word_lengths)

freq_dict = dict(Counter(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution

```
def freqCounter(_str):
    _txt=_str.split()
    freq_dict={}
    for word in _txt:
        c=0
        for letter in word:
           if letter not in "aeiou.,:;!?[]\"`()'":
               c+=1
        freq_dict[c]=freq_dict.get(c,0)+ 1
    return freq_dict

txt = "There is no new thing under the sun."
table=freqCounter(txt)
for k in table:
    print( k, ":", table[k])
```